# stored procedure does not use string in 'in' statement

Tags: mysql

How can I use the 'in' statement in a stored procedure where the value to the statement comes from the script...?

Lets say I have the folowing stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
IN v_act_date varchar(1024)
)
BEGIN
update db.my_table set upd=0 where act_date in (v_act_date);
END
```

And when I call it - it look like this:

```
v_act_date = "str_to_date('01-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y'),str_to_date('02-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y'),str_to_date('31-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y')"
v_act_date = replace(v_act_date,"'","''")
conn.execute("call test('" & v_act_date & "');")
```

If I do that nothing happes to my table - so I think it's not using the string 'v_act_date' as it should...

If I am using the sql-command directly in the script it works fine - like this:

```
v_act_date = "str_to_date('01-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y'),str_to_date('02-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y'),str_to_date('31-10-2021','%d-%m-%Y')"
conn.execute("update db.my_table set upd=0 where act_date in (" & v_act_date & ");")
```

So - how can I send a string to a stored procedure and use it in an 'in' statement..?

Thanks.

Comment: mysql date formats are `YYYY-MM-DD` not `DD-MM-YYYY`

Comment: The variable isn’t just put into the SQL string by itself. You either need dynamic SQL or converting the single string into a format suitable for the IN operator

Comment: Yes - that's why I am using str_to_date - to convert it... But it doesn't work either if I am using YYYY-MM-DD formatted dates... It's the 'IN' statement which doesn't get the string - I think.

Answer (score 0):

For that you nee dynamic sql.

But why not have a mysql for the dates, STR_TO_DATE needs processing power

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
IN v_act_date varchar(1024)
)
BEGIN

    SET @sql = CONCAT('update db.my_table set upd=0 where act_date in ( ',v_act_date,');');

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```